# Maven not executing any Cucumber tests

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am unable to run any Cucumber tests within my project using Maven. However, directly interacting with the tests in IntelliJ is no issue.

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java-skeleton</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Cucumber-Java Skeleton</name>

    <properties>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.8.0</cucumber.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: Structure of my project]

CucumberTestRunner Class

```
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;

@Cucumber
public class CucumberTestRunner {

    // See:
    // https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1149
    // https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine

}
```

Within the StepDefinitions Class and the Feature file are just arbitrary 1 + 1 = 2 assertions to initially prove this concept out.

When I execute `./mvnw clean install`, this is the output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/target/cucumber-java-skeleton-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/target/cucumber-java-skeleton-0.0.1.jar to /Users/.m2/repository/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/0.0.1/cucumber-java-skeleton-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/IdeaProjects/cucumber-java-skeleton/pom.xml to /Users/.m2/repository/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/0.0.1/cucumber-java-skeleton-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.618 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-01T13:17:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Maven (surefire) only runs test classes that end with `Test`.

Rename `CucumberTestRunner` to e.g. `RunCucumberTest`, or configure surefire to look for a different pattern.